# Get drag & drop to work in WPF which already works in Windows Forms

Tags: wpf, com, interop, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use this function from a COM API which enables the window to receive drops (as in drag & dop) from another application.

It is pretty straightforward in Windows Forms and works:

```
public void EnableDropSupport(System.Windows.Forms.Form form)
{
   IntPtr hwnd = form.Handle;
   _comAPI.RegisterDropWindow((int)hwnd);
}
```

But I have a WPF window where it does not work and I don't understand why. I have tried the following:

```
public void EnableDropSupport(System.Windows.Window window)
{
   window.AllowDrop = true;
   WindowInteropHelper windowInteropHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
   IntPtr hwnd = windowInteropHelper.Handle;
   _comAPI.RegisterDropWindow((int)hwnd);
}
```

The last two lines are basically identical but it will just not work in WPF. While

> window.AllowDrop = true;

will make it appear as if it will accept the drop, the drop event of that COM API is not raised.

**Am I missing something or can someone help?**

Comment: Why do you even need any kind of special COM function there? You should be able to handle all DnD scenarios with `AllowDrop` and the associated WPF DnD events.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what exactly `RegisterDropWindow` is actually doing. There isn't anything wrong with your code so far as I can see, but it may be that `RegisterDropWindow` code is somehow WinForms-specific, or at least not WPF-friendly.

Comment: RegisterDropWindow somehow enables drag & drop on the window. I cannot use WPF's drag & drop events since I need to respond to the drop event from the COM API. I hope it is not WinForms specific, that's why I wanted to know whether I am doing something wrong.

Comment: You're not missing anything on WPF side of things. Most likely the problem is with `RegisterDropWindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Pavel Minaev's answer (which he posted as a comment to the question) which was correct:

> You're not missing anything on WPF
>   side of things. Most likely the
>   problem is with RegisterDropWindow.